# group by substraction power bi

Tags: group-by, powerbi

I have data like this and I want to group on rows with substraction between dates

```
Customer   Date          price
Jane       01/01/2018    10
Jane       01/02/2018    14
Joe        01/01/2018    10
Joe        01/02/2018    15
```

I need to obtain:

```
Customer price
Jane     4
Joe      5
```

How to perform this in power Bi ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into a calculated column:

```
Difference = 
  var LatestDate = Table[Date] 
  var LatestValue = Table[Price]
  var PreviousDate = Dateadd(Table[Date],-1, day)
  var PreviousValue = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(Table[Price],1),
    FILTER(Table, Table[Date]=PreviousDate))
  RETURN IF(CONTAINS(Table,Table[Date],PreviousDate), LatestValue-PreviousValue , 0)
```